# How to CREATE tables with foreign keys POSTGRESQL

Tags: java, sql

I want to CREATE 4 tables that has FOREIGN KEYS of each other.

table `students` :

```
CREATE TABLE students
(
  PRIMARY KEY (student_id),
  student_id SERIAL,
  student_name VARCHAR(100),
  student_age  INT,
  entry_year INT,
  graduate_year INT,
  faculty_name VARCHAR(100),
  group_id INT,
  FOREIGN KEY (group_id) REFERENCES groups(group_id)
);
```

table `groups` :

```
  CREATE TABLE groups
  (
PRIMARY KEY (group_id),
group_id   SERIAL,
group_name VARCHAR(100),
  student_id INT,
FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES students(student_id)
  );
```

table `lessons` :

```
CREATE TABLE lessons
(
  PRIMARY KEY (lesson_id),
  lesson_id  SERIAL,
  lesson_name  VARCHAR(100),
  class_number INT,
  date TIMESTAMP,
  teacher_id INT,
  group_id INT,
  FOREIGN KEY(teacher_id) REFERENCES teachers(teacher_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (group_id) REFERENCES groups(group_id)
   );
```

table `teachers` :

```
CREATE TABLE teachers
(
  PRIMARY KEY (teacher_id),
  teacher_id INT,
  teacher_name VARCHAR(100),
  position VARCHAR(100)
);
```

And when I run this query in Java application, I gain an error with creation table `students` :

```
nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "groups" does not exist
```

I know why It exception throwed.
Because I am creating table `students` with foreign key from table `groups` which has not yet been created.

But I have no idea how to fix It. Thanks in advance for response!

Comment: Create the tables first, then add the fk's.

Comment: How to add fk's after creation?

Comment: alter table add etc

Comment: https://tableplus.com/blog/2018/08/postgresql-how-to-add-a-foreign-key.html

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE students
(
  PRIMARY KEY (student_id),
  student_id SERIAL,
  student_name VARCHAR(100),
  student_age  INT,
  entry_year INT,
  graduate_year INT,
  faculty_name VARCHAR(100),
  group_id INT,
  CONSTRAINT fk_group
    FOREIGN KEY(group_id) 
      REFERENCES groups(group_id)
);
```

https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-foreign-key/